# Script SQL para ajustar vírgula dos decimais de uma coluna - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, administração-postgresql

Tenho uma tabela no PostgreSQL que possui o campo `IdProduto` e `Quantidade`.
Os valores da coluna `Quantidade` foram gravados com decimais errados.

Ex: Foi gravado `9000,000` quando deveria ser `9,000`. A falta de vírgula fez com que o valor subisse de 9 unidades para 9 mil.

Existe uma maneira de eu acertar isso via script SQL para todos os produtos?

Comment: Qual o tipo dessa coluna? Se der um exemplo mais completo da estrutura da tabela e mais exemplos dos dados fica mais fácil para o pessoal da comunidade ajudar.

Comment: Se for um campo numérico faz um update de tudo dividindo por mil, tipo `update [tabela] set [campo] = [campo]/1000;`. Pra uma resposta mais detalhada, melhore a pergunta: acrescente o schema da sua tabela e um ou dois registros de exemplo...

Comment: @CamiloSantos, o tipo é Numeric...